# ko.observableArray and JSON data massaging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I'm using web services to load data to client side. For binding purposes I need to expand on data that I get. I.e. I don't want to massage all data on server side.

For example, object `Trip { Id: "123", Status: "P" }`

In HTML I bind `table` to observableArray and want to display "Pending" instead of "P".
I'm coming from Silverlight/MVVM and usually you would use converter or just add new R/O property to object.

Not sure how this scenario should be handled in knockout.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for a converter, `computed` observables are a good candidate.

```
var Tip = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.id;
    self.status = ko.observable(data.status);

    //You may prefer fullStatus, or statusName
    self.statusConverter = ko.computed(function() { 
        return self.statusMap[self.status()];
    });
};

Tip.prototype.statusMap = {
    P: "Pending",
    O: "Open",
    C: "Closed"
};
```

which you can bind to like this:

```
<td data-bind="text: statusConverter"></td>
```

You can see it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/eHrEB/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You may find here all you need :

http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/knockout-succinctly/

Have a good read.